# JSON Grail Groovy Update SQL

Tags: sql, grails, groovy, sql-update

Using a Groovy script with grails and want to do an update to a record in the database.  I do the basic get the object from JSON and convert it to the Domain class and then do save() on it.  From what I understand since I am new to Groovy and grails the save should update if the "id" is already there.  But I don't get that, I get the standard SQL error of "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'".  How do I fix this?

```
def input = request.JSON
def instance = new Recorders(input)
instance.id = input.getAt("id")
instance.save()
```

and my domain is:

```
class Recorders {

Integer sdMode
Integer gsmMode

static mapping = {
    id generator: "assigned"
}

static constraints = {
    sdMode nullable: true
    gsmMode nullable: true
}
}
```

Comment: as Rob Hruska point out, you must get the object from database & update it; not creating a new one with duplicate id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a `new Recorders(input)`, you probably ought to `get` it:

```
def input = request.JSON
def instance = Recorders.get(input.getAt('id'))
instance.properties = input
instance.save()
```

**Edit**

(From your comment) If it doesn't exist and you want to insert it:

```
def input = request.JSON
def id = input.getAt('id')
def instance = Recorders.get(id)
if(!instance) {
    instance = new Recorders(id: id)
}
instance.properties = input
instance.save()
```

I don't use assigned id generators much, so I'm not sure if Grails will bind the id automatically (since it's expecting it to be assigned). If it does, you can probably remove the `id: id` from the `Recorders()` constructor.

Comment: What if its not there then I want it to insert...I guess I should have put that in the question too.

Comment: Doesn't work getting  ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():

Comment: The instance.properties = input doesn't work all the fields are null

Comment: I had to add instance.sdMode = input.getAt("sdMode") and instance.gsmMode = input.getAt("gsmMode")  weird cause I know that instance.properties = has worked before....

Comment: Glad you got it to work. There's probably a way to get the binding to work. There's an [open Grails bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5585) about JSON binding, but I only skimmed it; not sure if it applies to your situation or not.